# Why is Elixir's Enum.sum so fast?

Tags: elixir

When running

```
1..10000000000000000000 |> Enum.sum
```

The result is computed in what seems like constant time - I assume it uses the formula `1+ 2+ ... + n = n(n+1) / 2`

What allows elixir to make this optimization? is the 1..n notation different than declaring a normal list as `[1,2,3]`. When I inspect `1..100000` it appears to return a string. What's going on here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`1..10000000000000000000` is a `Range` and Elixir has a special case in `Enum.sum` for ranges which uses the integer summation formula:

```
def sum(first..last) when last > first do
  div((last + first) * (last - first + 1), 2)
end
```

[Source](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/ca88be4ad171e29259a8e0c962de749d9e9c2e8e/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L2300-L2302)

Comment: Makes total sense - I didn't realize there was an intermediary Range that would allow that kind of optimization. Thanks!

Comment: pattern matching ftw :-)